# Select groups where all values are positive

Tags: r

I have a data frame called dates with 4 columns (Number, A, B, and Diff). Number is a grouping variable. A and B are both date columns. 'Diff' is a column with the number of days in between A and B.

Within each 'Number', I want to *delete* the entire group if 'Diff' contains *any negative* number. Or phrased the other way around: only *keep* groups if *all* values are positive.

```
Number            A                B                Diff
  1            2015-06-08      2015-06-06            -2
  1            2015-06-08      2015-06-06            -2
  2            2015-06-01      2015-05-25            -7
  2            2015-06-01      2015-06-06             5 
  3            2015-06-04      2015-06-07             3 
  3            2015-06-04      2015-06-06             2
```

My desired result is the group where 'Number' is 3, where all values are positive. Both group Number 1 and Number 2 are removed because both groups contain at least one negative value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, if(!any(Diff < 0)) .SD, by = Number]
#   Number          A          B Diff
#1:      3 2015-06-04 2015-06-07    3
#2:      3 2015-06-04 2015-06-06    2
```

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
      group_by(Number) %>%
      filter(all(Diff>=0))
```

Comment: Uuuu I was just posting `setDT(df)[, if(all(Diff >= 0)) .SD, by = Number]` ;)

Comment: @DavidArenburg That looks more neat, without having to negate

Comment: Thank you!!. Just curious - what does the .SD do?

Comment: @TD `.SD` means `Subset of Data.table`.  i.e we are getting a subset of the dataset,  If we specify the `.SDcols`, `.SD` will return only that columns specified in that.

Answer (score 3):

Base R possibility

```
df[with(df, ave(Diff, Number, FUN = function(x) any(x < 0))) == 0,]
#   Number          A          B Diff
# 5      3 2015-06-04 2015-06-07    3
# 6      3 2015-06-04 2015-06-06    2
```

Or a shorter version (per comments)

```
df[with(df, ave(Diff >= 0, Number, FUN = all)), ]
```

Comment: Or avoiding the anonymous function `df[with(df, ave(Diff>=0, Number, FUN=all)),]`